# Should a new asphalt driveway have rough sections where stones are showing?

Tags: driveway, asphalt

My wife and I recently purchased a newly built home.  Our 6 week old asphalt driveway has numerous sections that are very rough, with lots of stones in the aggregate showing (the consistency in places reminds me of a rice krispie treat).  The builder had the paving company inspect the driveway and they are telling me this is normal and does not need repair.  I do not know enough to be sure, but this doesn't seem right to me.  Thoughts?

**EDIT**

Two pics, the first shows an area that is really gravelly. The second shows an area that is very pocked.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post a picture?

Comment: @Steven, yes, I'll do it as soon as I get home tonight, thanks.

Comment: Yes its normal.. for cheaply laid asphalt. Its just a mixture of aggregate and tar and the aggregate will loosen for a while and/or be inconsistent in smoothness. Better laid asphalt is pressed with a roller, re tarred, re pressed until nice and smooth.. but costs more obviously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They look normal to me, however, you may want to seal them.  There are various sealing products out there like [Latex-ite 4-Gallon Acrylic Plus Driveway Revitalizer Filler/Sealer](http://www.homedepot.com/Building-Materials-Concrete-Cement-Masonry-Driveway-Products/h_d1/N-5yc1vZaromZ1z0yhyj/R-202894876/h_d2/ProductDisplay?catalogId=10053&langId=-1&storeId=10051) from [The Home Depot](http://www.homedepot.com) or [Driveaseal 4.75 Gallon Blacktop Driveway Sealer](http://www.lowes.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/ProductDisplay?langId=-1&storeId=10151&catalogId=10051&cId=SEARCH&productId=1086079&cm_mmc=SCE_gps-_-gps-_-gps-_-Driveaseal%204.75%20Gallon%20Blacktop%20Driveway%20Sealer&CAWELAID=1024018399), [BLACK JACK 4.75 Gallon Drive-Maxx 700 Advanced Gel Blacktop Driveway Filler & Sealer](http://www.lowes.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/ProductDisplay?langId=-1&storeId=10151&catalogId=10051&cId=SEARCH&productId=3025364&cm_mmc=SCE_gps-_-gps-_-gps-_-BLACK%20JACK%204.75%20Gallon%20Drive-Maxx%20700%20Advanced%20Gel%20Blacktop%20Driveway%20Filler%20&%20Sealer&CAWELAID=1024209110), and [BLACK JACK 4.75-Gallon Asphalt Sealer](http://www.lowes.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/ProductDisplay?langId=-1&storeId=10151&catalogId=10051&cId=SEARCH&productId=3402814&cm_mmc=SCE_gps-_-gps-_-gps-_-BLACK%20JACK%204.75-Gallon%20Asphalt%20Sealer&CAWELAID=1024053803) from [Lowes](http://www.lowes.com).